# pydrake.tutorials ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydrake'

Tags: python-3.x, drake

Installation steps were:

```
git clone https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake.git
mkdir drake-build
cd drake-build
cmake -DWITH_GUROBI=ON -DWITH_MOSEK=ON ../drake
make -j4
cd drake-build
export PYTHONPATH=${PWD}/install/lib/python3.8/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}
```

When I try `python3 -m pydrake.tutorials` I have got this error:

```
~/git/drake-build$ python3 -m pydrake.tutorials
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'pydrake.tutorials' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydrake')
```

And when i use `python3 -c 'import pydrake; print(pydrake.__file__)'`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydrake'
```

Comment: Why can't you just install using pip? This is the module you are trying to install right? https://drake.mit.edu/pip.html#stable-releases

Comment: because I want to use Gurobi solver.

Comment: That seems to be the correct steps to build, as documented at https://drake.mit.edu/from_source.html.

What OS version are you using?  `python3.8` suggests Ubuntu 20.04, is that true?

Comment: I ran those exact commands on Ubuntu 20, and the tutorials worked for me.  Were there any warning or error message during the build?  Maybe it failed before finishing?

Comment: I have ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `export PYTHONPATH=...` step must be performed in the same command-line terminal as `python3 -m pydrake.tutorials` is later attempted.  Maybe that was the problem?

Comment: I reinstall program and it started work.